# Can't access the database on windows server using dotnet core 2.1

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I am getting this message when I try to connect the .net core app hosted on IIS, on amazon windows server, to a RDS SQL Server instance - also on amazon:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

But when try to connect to the RDS from my local pc using SQL Server I can login successfully, also tested this on my local IIS and I can access the remote db.[image]

Comment: Maybe you are missing a port?

Comment: tried that too - it’s not that

Comment: Is the web app running under different credentials than what you're connecting with locally?

Comment: Is your app pool Identity running under NetworkService? Can you post your connection string (replace sensitive info with asterisks)?

Comment: i added an image describing the problem

Comment: @johnluke.laue yes, the identity is okay